# Convergence and Crash of a derivation (Chomsky)

Tags: formal-languages

I would like to pose you a terminological question, regarding the following quotes from Noam Chomsky's work:

> "A strong feature must be eliminated (almost) immediately upon its
>   introduction into the phrase marker; otherwise, the derivation
>   cancels."
>
> "A strong feature that is not checked (and eliminated) in overt syntax
>   causes a derivation to crash at LF." [LF= Logical Form]
>
> " ‘‘strong’’ features are visible at PF and ‘‘weak’’ features
>   invisible at PF. These features are not legitimate objects at PF; they
>   are not proper components of phonetic matrices. Therefore, if a strong
>   feature remains after Spell-Out, the derivation crashes."
>
> "Alternatively, weak features are deleted in the PF component so that
>   PF rules can apply to the phonological matrix that remains; strong
>   features are not deleted so that PF rules do not apply, causing the
>   derivation to crash at PF." [PF = Phonetic Form]
>
> "The language L determines a set of *derivations* (computations). A
>   derivation *converges* at one of the interface levels [PF, LF] if it
>   yields a representation satisfying FI [FI = Full Interpretation] at
>   this level, and *converges* if it converges at both interface levels,
>   PF and LF; otherwise, it *crashes*. "

Chomsky is taking some kind of computer-science terminology, but I am not sure whether he makes some systematic and standard use of the terms or whether he just loosely hovers around them. The idea of a computation crashing (or being blocked with no chance of going forward, or of the system collapsing, whatever) seems quite intuitive, but, does it refer to a technical use from his part? I am more interested, though, in the rationale behind "convergence". Does it mean the derivation converges to a numerical value $0$?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: and which work of Chomsky are you citing?

Comment: The Minimalist Program, MIT Press, 1995.

Answer (score 1):

From a theoretical computer science point of view, to "crash" is not standardly a technical term. (Of course computer scientists speak informally about programs crashing, but usually not as a technically well-defined thing).

"Covergence" in the sense of the quote sounds less informal, but is still not quite standard. What *is* standard, however, is to speak of a computation "diverging" if it goes on forever without reaching a result, so using "converge" about a computation that *does* yield a result is not too far off. (The more conventional word choice would be "terminate", however).

Comment: Does this use of convergence have anything to do with convergence to zero in functional analysis and the like?

Comment: @JavierArias: Only indirectly, and not, I'd think, in any terribly enlightening way.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm. Thanks a lot. Wasn't there in functional analysis some requirement for a kernel to be symmetric that i some cases its only value be zero or something like that? I am telling that because of the use linguists make of kernels, albeit in a different context.

Comment: Mkholm. Never mind. I am probably way off the target.

Comment: @Javier: Doesn't ring any bell for me. (Also, I suspect [functional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis) doesn't mean what you think it does; it would make more sense for you to be talking about ordinary real analysis here).

Comment: I am trying to find an equivalent for the weak and strong features in Chomsky. Maybe the distinction between weak operator topology and strong operator topology? Or am I just guessing randomly?

Comment: @JavierArias: I don't completely understand what he's saying based on your quotes, but yes, it sounds like you're just guessing randomly. In particular, it sounds (both in this question and in your other ones) that you have a tendency to think that just because the same _word_ is used in different areas of mathematics, there must necessarily be a deep analogy between their uses. But reality is not so nice and tidy -- people chose words for their technical concepts willy-nilly and without coordinating with anyone.

Comment: What one _should_ do is comparing the mathematical _content_ of the definitions. If one finds a _structural_ similarity that aligns with coincidences of naming, one can begin wondering if it was a coincidence after all. But without any such similarity of meaning, your _default_ assumption should be that the homonymymous terms are just a meaningless coincidence because there are only so many words to choose from and authors will grasp at the most tenuous and random analogies to name their concepts.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm. Thanks for your reply. Your are absolutely right about the perils of uncautious extension of analogies from one field into another (what some philosophers call "catabasis", I believe). Anyway, the default case should be, precisely, that coherence in the use of terms prevails, specially the more formalized a discipline is. I have always found frustrating the plaethora of terminological overlappings and confusions within linguistics, and it seems that mathematics is not as free from ambiguity as one has always been taught.

Comment: I have just created a specific thread for it:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084883/chomsky-feynman-thom

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19829/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-convergence-and-crash-of-a-derivation-c).

Comment: I have moved the comment thread [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19829/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-convergence-and-crash-of-a-derivation-c), since it was long and veered off the answer. I have left the beginning to some point I deemed close enough to the answer and the link to the new question (for the convenience of interested parties) stand here.

Comment: @JavierArias, I am afraid that your idea that the default case should be coherence in the use of terms is absurdly against all evidence. For example, your coming up with weak and strong topologies in the context of anything related to Chomsky is just incoherent :(

Answer (score 0):

- What could be a "crash" in the domain of computation?   One of the
  questions in computation theory is if the mathematical machine under
  consideration is able to terminate on its input or not, this means:
  Is it able to finish its computation in a finite number of steps?

  For those inputs where a machine does not terminate, it will go
  through all it its states, without ever reaching a final state. For
  example it traverses an endless loop.

  So that is more a "hang" than a "crash".
- What could Chomsky mean?

  What I read so far looks similar to the derivation processes of
  formal languages
  ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)). There, a
  similiar problem to the termination of a machine function shows up in
  the question of generating / deriving a sentence from some start
  symbol using the rules of the grammar in finite many steps.

  That cited derivation of the minimalist program
  ([link](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalistisches_Programm))
  seems about natural language, processed by a brain.
  Some part of the brain seems to produce sentences via similar
  derivations steps and a talk part (PF) and a think part (LF) of the 
  brain watch this and if they accept the result, it is called convergence.

  I personally never heard the term "convergence" used for a successful 
  (= terminating) derivation in the context of formal languages.

  The term convergence in the mathematical context is usually associated 
  with an successful approximation process of some kind, where one
  gets closer to some object, starting with sequences of numbers usually.

  The derivation of formal languages is all about deciding if a sentence belongs 
  to language or not, if it is well formed. 
  The "is element of" relation $\in$ just has the values true ($1$) or false ($0$).

  So I wonder if that MP-derivation-convergence is about the convergence of
  some sequence $(\in_k)_{\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\{ 0, 1 \}$ or $\{ 0, 1 \}^2$ (the set of pairs of numbers from $\{ 0, 1\}$), 
  the $k$-th member related to the $k$-th derivation step.

Comment: Well, but keep in mind that the analogy has its limits, since we are talking about the human mind / brain computing a sentence that has effectively heard or just milliseconds before uttering it....so the fact that computation is not deterred for eternity is a given....crash in this sense would mean collapse and then move on (to trying to produce another sentence, for instance), and not an aeternal loop. In other words, collapse would mean some crucial violation of well-formedness has been detected at some point of the derivation.

Comment: @JavierArias I gave my thoughts, but I lack the knowledge of that linguistic MP derivation to be of substantial help.

Comment: @nwm That is fine.